# Setting the "Title" value displayed in Visual Studio's "Attach to Process" dialog?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-services, visual-studio-debugging

When you choose Debug / Attach to Process in Visual Studio, the dialog displayed has a "Title" column. By default this shows the caption of the main window belonging to the process. For example, it might display "It was a dark and stormy night - Notepad".

How can I set this field for an application that doesn't have a main window (e.g. a Windows service)?

I have multiple services running with the same executable name, and I'd like to be able to easily differentiate between them when attaching.

Comment: No solution found yet?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a batch file and it will tell you the identity of the worker process:

```
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list wp
pause
```

This doesn't give you a title but will identify them when attaching

Comment: That only works for ASP.NET worker processes -- although it does tell you which app pool (when VS only tells you the user). I'm talking about normal Windows Services.