# How to show a WCF service "title" for the Attach to Process dialog

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, debugging

What property do I need to set in my Windows hosted WCF services so that a "Title" value will appear in the Debug "Attach to Process" dialog (as in the WcfSvcHost.exe entries below)?:

[image]

We are using the `ServiceProcessInstaller` & `ServiceInstaller` classes. I tried setting both the `ServiceInstaller.DisplayName` & `ServiceInstaller.DisplayName` properties but no change.

Comment: See if my post [here][1] helps


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326046/setting-the-title-value-displayed-in-visual-studios-attach-to-process-dialo/8340706#8340706

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WcfSvcHost.exe processes are the WCF service host processes started by Visual Studio when you start a debug session within a solution, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552363.aspx. There is no way to specify a title for these processes.

Normally the title column would be filled for applications that host a user interface. For example, look at the Task Manager dialog, Applications tab. The applications shown there do have a title and these are displayed equally in the debug attach process window.

Starting the WCF service hosts by Visual Studio completely bypasses the `ServiceProcessInstaller` and `ServiceInstaller` classes, so no chance of getting it in that way. When you start (self) hosting your WCF service in a UI (winforms/WPF) application, you have the best chance of getting the title filled and being able to find your process.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. I am now installing the services instead.